# Find cells with 3x3 window

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst

I have a raster and need to only identify cells that are adjacent within a 3x3 window.[image]

I tried various tools but without any success. My current cells are 1x1 and currently using ArcGIS.

Comment: we cannot have raster data with different pixel size as you have mentioned in the sample image

Comment: This is a more complicated task than it seems at first. Have a look at the method discussed in [this similar question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/253156/packing-squares-polygons-in-a-raster-grid). It looks like the custom script that was discussed there, was never created or at least not shared. But perhaps you can take a similar approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use arcpy and numpy, no need for Spatial Analyst. Convert your raster to 0 and 1, with 1 as your grey areas and use this as `in_raster`:

```py
import arcpy
import numpy as np

in_raster = r'C:\Test\randraster_1_0.tif'
to_find = np.ones(shape=(2,2)) #2 rows, 2 columns of ones. Change to 3,3 to find 3x3 matrix
output_raster = r'C:\Test\resultraster.tif' #Resulting raster. Will be 1 where your matrix is found and 0 everywhere else.

def im2col(A,BLKSZ):
    #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32531377/how-can-i-check-if-one-two-dimensional-numpy-array-contains-a-specific-pattern-o
    M,N = A.shape
    col_extent = N - BLKSZ[1] + 1
    row_extent = M - BLKSZ[0] + 1
    start_idx = np.arange(BLKSZ[0])[:,None]*N + np.arange(BLKSZ[1])
    offset_idx = np.arange(row_extent)[:,None]*N + np.arange(col_extent)
    return np.take (A,start_idx.ravel()[:,None] + offset_idx.ravel())

arr = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(in_raster)
col_match = im2col(arr,to_find.shape) == to_find.ravel()[:,None]
out_shape = np.asarray(arr.shape) - np.asarray(to_find.shape) + 1
R,C = np.where(col_match.all(0).reshape(out_shape))
resultarr = np.zeros(shape=arr.shape)

for idx in zip(R.tolist(),C.tolist()): 
    resultarr[idx[0]:idx[0]+to_find.shape[0],idx[1]:idx[1]+to_find.shape[1]] = 1 #Im sure there is a better way of indexing...

desc = arcpy.Describe(in_raster+r'/Band_1')
arcpy.env.outputCoordinateSystem = desc.spatialReference
resultraster = arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster(in_array=resultarr, lower_left_corner=desc.extent.lowerLeft, x_cell_size=desc.meanCellHeight, y_cell_size=desc.meanCellWidth)
resultraster.save(output_raster)
```

[image]